# Applet component location on screen changes when running in eclipse and in a browser

Tags: java, swing, applet, components, layout-manager

I am moving components around and I am setting their locations to that of other components, but its not exact. So what I did was move the component a little to the left and a little up to fix that, but when I run it in the browser, it is off even more. What can I do about it and why isnt the location exact?

Edit: Fixed it by calculating the differences in the locations of the components

Comment: *"What can I do about it"*  [Use layouts](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/).

Comment: *"Applet component location on screen changes.." ..when I drag the browser or scroll the page with the applet.  So the applet should never be setting the location of components relative to anything but itself.  Forget the screen coordinates.

Comment: I am using layouts, thats why I have to get the location on screen instead of using normal getLocation(). If I use getLocation(), itll give me the location in the panel and I have multiple panels

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Comment: @rasen58 *"I am using layouts, thats why I have to get the location on screen"* That doesn't make sense, if you're using the Swing's layout managers, then it should all be taken care for you...

Comment: @MadProgrammer Sorry, I just realized how i phrased it wrong, the component (A) that I want to move is in a layered pane and the location of where I want to move it is the location of another component (B) in another panel. When I use getLocation on the component B, it returns a low value such as (10, 15), when it is actually much higher (20, 150) [relative to the root panel].

Comment: @rasen58 Sample code will go a long way

Comment: However, I fixed it, I calculated the difference in the locations and moved the component by that much.